# Bootstrap responsive audio player

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, audio

I need help.
When I'm using an audio in the container (bootstrap) I have 4 player in 1 row - that's fine (col-lg-3), but when I'm resizing my window (from col-md-4 to col-xs-6) then magic happens... players are in different places :/ you can look at this here:

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <p class="titles">Bird Wings</p>
        <audio class="audio controls">
        <source src="http://audiosoundclips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Dogbark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <p class="titles">Bird Wings</p>
        <audio class="audio controls">
        <source src="http://audiosoundclips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Dogbark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <p class="titles">Bird Wings</p>
        <audio class="audio controls">
        <source src="http://audiosoundclips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Dogbark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <p class="titles">Bird Wings</p>
        <audio class="audio controls">
        <source src="http://audiosoundclips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Dogbark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you add a link to a jsfiddle (or similar) so that it can be easily tested?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, simple mistakes - no quotation marks :/